# How to force private visibility to child's method on an abstract class abstract method?

Tags: java, polymorphism, private, abstract

I would like to force my abstract class children to implement my abstract method as private.
Is that possible?

Comment: What's the motivation?

Comment: Whats wrong with `protected`?

Comment: Abstract class has a final method beFit() that calls implemented abstract methods run() and feedBetter(). I want those methods to not be accessible within the package

Comment: that has to be `protected` considering your subclass won't be able to see it to override it if it's `private`

Comment: provide reason , then we may be able to provide solution

Comment: @user1352530 I'm not sure I understand your comment. Can you post your code?

Comment: Subclasses can only increase visibility, never reduce it. For a good reason as well.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce. If I make them protected, I am enabling other classes to use those methods inconsistenly. Perhaps I want run() and feedBetter() be executed always in the same order, that's why I wrap its execution in a final method

Answer (score 3):

The visibility of an overriding method can not be less than that of overriden method.
That is to say, you can't override a public method and make it protected OR private.

since abstract methods are either protected OR public apart from default (since they are supposed to be overriden by sub-classes), the implementation of the method can not be private.

Answer (score 2):

First @Ravinder Reddy's answer is absolutely right and you should NOT use my example without accepting my terms and conditions which basically state("Use at your own risk").

I can't say its pretty or useful but I assume you can do something like:

```
public abstract class Master {}

public abstract class Super extends Master{
    protected abstract void foo();
}

public class Sub extends Master {

    private Inner inner = new Inner();

    private void foo() {
        inner.foo();
    }

    private class Inner extends Super {
        @Override
        protected void foo() {
            System.out.println("foo");
        }
    }

}
```

PS: I don't think it is useful in any way(I'm not even sure this will work).